# Detect location, browser and device type from cloudfront logs using Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-athena

can any one help regarding the Athena logs and able extract useful information.

Comment: Welcome to SO Vinod. This question is pretty vague so I'm flagging as unclear. I recommend editing to include substantially more detail.

Answer (score 0):

From [Querying Amazon CloudFront Logs - Amazon Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/cloudfront-logs.html):

> You can configure Amazon CloudFront CDN to export Web distribution access logs to Amazon S3. Use these logs to explore users’ surfing patterns across your web properties served by CloudFront.

You can create a table with:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS default.cloudfront_logs (
  `date` DATE,
  time STRING,
  location STRING,
  bytes BIGINT,
  requestip STRING,
  method STRING,
  host STRING,
  uri STRING,
  status INT,
  referrer STRING,
  useragent STRING,
  querystring STRING,
  cookie STRING,
  resulttype STRING,
  requestid STRING,
  hostheader STRING,
  requestprotocol STRING,
  requestbytes BIGINT,
  timetaken FLOAT,
  xforwardedfor STRING,
  sslprotocol STRING,
  sslcipher STRING,
  responseresulttype STRING,
  httpversion STRING,
  filestatus STRING,
  encryptedfields INT
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
LOCATION 's3://CloudFront_bucket_name/AWSLogs/Account_ID/'
TBLPROPERTIES ( 'skip.header.line.count'='2' )
```

The `useragent` field identifies the source of the request, such as the type of device and browser that submitted the request and, if the request came from a search engine, which search engine.

The `location` field merely identifies which **Amazon CloudFront edge location** was used when accessing the content.

For a better location indicator, you could use an [IP Geo Lookup Service](https://www.google.com/search?q=lookup+ip+location) to obtain a location from the IP address.

See: [Amazon CloudFront log file format](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/AccessLogs.html#LogFileFormat)